# Rigged blender model is deformed when imported into Unity

Tags: unity, animation, blender, fbx, rigging

I am facing a strange problem with a model I rigged in Blender. Everything in Blender seems fine:

- All scales and rotations are normalized
- There is no unassigned vertex
- There is no weight bleeding from other bones

[image: seems fine]

However when I imported the model in Unity, I am faced with some distortion happening  in some of the model's meshes (it is a composite model).

[image: some distortion happening]

Note that this doesn't seem to be happening for all bones or mesh components, but only for a couple of them.

Does anyone have any clue about why this is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this by noticing that in Blender the model was rotate 90° on the Z axis, which meant that the FBX exporter was getting confused over certain transforms.

By rotating this so that the axis were as supposed in blender and normalizing the rotation (`Ctrl+a > rotation`) I managed to solve this!